# hadoop mapreduce jobs parallely

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

we are executing 10 MapReduce jobs at a time but only 6 are running 4 are in pending state

how to execute all the jobs parallelly in apache Hadoop

i tried fairscheduler and capacity scheduler in all 4 node master +gateway_2 datanodes

Comment: Have you tried reducing the needed memory for each mapreduce container so that yarn can run more at the same time?