# Hadoop Cluster only executing 2 jobs per data nodes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a apache hadoop cluster with one gateway node, one master (also datanode) and 2 datanodes built on ubuntu 20. It has hadoop, hive, spark, mysql installed.

When I run 10 concurrent jobs 5 mapreduce and 5 spark  jobs, only 6 are executing simultaneously and 4 are in accepted state. Once the 6 executes then only the next 4 will run.

I have tried increasing `mapreduce.map.tasks` to 15 but it doesnt help.

I am running

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /opt/spark-3.1.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.2.jar 10
```

and

```
hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.0.jar pi 16 1000
```

Any solution will be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like your YARN cluster needs more resources. Open the YARN UI and see why jobs are stuck. Increasing tasks will only make the issue worse

Comment: This also seems to be a duplicate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76506398/hadoop-mapreduce-jobs-parallely